# how to set session timeout when user is idle for 5 min in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

how to set session timeout when user is idle for 5 min in cakephp

if in that 5 min user make query(or go to any page in site) in cake php then that session again refresh to 5 min.

session only and only timeout when user do nothing till 5min.

Comment: Isn't that a server setting?

Comment: use `cookie` for this.

Comment: Why can you not use a jquery timeout?

Comment: @yogesh-suthar can you give me some code about it

Answer (score 1):

Checking the great CakePHP book combined with some common sense solves most of these basic issues. [Go there](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html) and scroll down to sessions.

In short: Open APP/Config/core.php and scroll down to the session configuration, for me its around line 190 and add the timeout to the session configuration. Read the book page I've linked, there more settings you might want to read about.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'timeout' => 300
));
```